# turning java array elements into a sentence

Tags: java, arrays

I need to take the elements in my array, and use it to make an output message like this "your sentence is (this is where the elements would go)".  But the only way i know how to do it is with a for loop.

```
private void sentanceArray() {
        int size = 0;
        String word = "";
        int i = 0;


        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How many words would you like to enter?");

        size = input.nextInt();

         String [] sentance = new String[size];

        System.out.println("Please enter a word.");

        word = input.next();

        while( i < size){
           if( i < size){
                sentance[i] = word;
                i++;
                System.out.println("Please enter another word.");

                word = input.next();

           }//end of if 
        }//end of while

        displayArray(sentance);
    } // end of sentanceArray


    public static void displayArray(String []sentance){

        for(int i = 0; i < sentance.length; i++){               
            System.out.print( "Your sentance is " + sentance[i] +"\t" );
        }

    }//end of displayResults
```

My problem is that it is displaying "Your sentance is" and then only one element at a time

Comment: Why don't you do it in a for loop then?

Comment: One thing you should do is move the "your sentence is" to before the loop otherwise it will print multiple times.

Comment: Thanks im sad i didnt think of moving that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
System.out.print("Your sentence is ");
for(String x : sentance)
    System.out.print(x + "\t");
```

Also,

```
   while( i < size){
       if( i < size){ // You dont need this condition, while loop checks for that
```

Comment: it worked! sorry for the lack of info, first time doing this stuff